# Using Identity with Asp.net core API project

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-identity, membership

I am asking if it is possible to add ** Identity 
** membership tables to my *"SQL server database **
When I am working in **.net core webapi project *"
If yes please give me a reference 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, here is a link to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Here are links that can help you:

[How to Setup and Configure Identity Membership System in ASP.NET Core](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-setup/)

[How To Implement Authentication Using Identity Model In ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-implement-authentication-using-identity-model-in-asp-net-core/)

for Api:

[Using asp net identity with Web API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y02ccL4-_K4)

Comment: thank you guys but this is Not My Question ... all the example you sent using MVC I am using webApi project .. and I have My own sql server db I want to add Identity Models (tables) to My Existing DB